# What should keep in mind while researching a projector to purchase?

Tags: projector

Disclaimer: This is not a question about which projector to buy, as this kind of question is usually not useful on SE.

I may buy my first projector soon. It will be used primarily for streaming HD videos/movies in a living room, from diverse sources (laptop, BD player, other boxes). It will be mounted to the ceiling (normal middle european height - 220-230cm or so), the maximum area to be filled by the image is about 3m wide, but it is not necessary to actually use that up fully, I believe. Sitting distance is about 3-4m away. It will be used during the day and the night. Obviously I accept a very limited viewing experience during the day.

What are the important technical points I need to look at when deciding between different models? Obviously it needs the correct inputs for whatever players I want to attach to it. Then I will likely have to look hard at the cost of the device vs. the cost and frequency of replacing the bulb. And noise may play a role.

Is there a industry-wide comparable measure for luminosity? Does image quality differ wildly these days or is it basically sorted? What else is important?

Comment: Just playing on that intention, this falls under technical support. To answer the questions in your last paragraph, you are going to want to look for "lumens". Resolution and refresh rate should be your next measures of quality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's looking for general purchasing advice, which isn't within our scope.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, after reading the help center more closely it seems like I indeed misunderstood this part of SE - it seems like exactly the kind of question that is not acceptable on, for example, SO, is the one that is *required* here; so instead of asking about help on how to research which hardware would fit my needs, I should be asking about concrete models. What do you say - should I reformulate this question or delete it and create a new one?

Comment: Yep. Shopping is off-topic on SO, but it's the whole purpose of this site, so ask away. Which of those you do is up to you - if keeping this question but editing would help, you can do that, or delete and re-ask if that's easier.